# How to run mongo in a test stage?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, jenkins

I have a simple nodejs app setup with jenkins, however the test stage needs `mongodb` to run and my current `jenkinsfile` doesn't start a mongo container, so how can I do this?

This is my current `jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:8-alpine' 
            args '-p 3000:3000' 
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm install' 
            }
        }
        stage('Test') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm test' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen some answers on SO say that docker-compose would be used in a case like this but I figured maybe there's another way to just run a mongo container with docker before the test stage starts. Is this possible?

Comment: This is covered under ['Running "Sidecar" Containers" on the Using Docker with Pipeline Jenkins documentation page](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers).

Comment: @davidmaze the syntax in that link is a little different to what I have. I'm not sure how to combine them.